# Word for an object that alters the course of your life?

Tags: single-word-requests

When learning about people, either through biographic readings or in person, I'm very interested to learn which "object" has had the single greatest effect on them. For example, what has made an indelible mark that changed their life, or "altered the colour of [their] mind", or imputed unto them a goal or a passion they've been chasing ever since. I suppose a person can have more than one of these objects, but we usually have only one for any given context.

These type of objects are usually books or music albums, and I want to know which of them are esteemed in this way, because those are exactly the objects I want to add to my personal collection.

I liked "lodestar" for a bit, but it implies an everlasting guide that one can reliably call upon, or to extend the metaphor, implies something that one still necessarily believes in.

Comment: The terms I have heard most often used for this are simply *life-changing book* and *life-changing music/album*.

Comment: Aw. I was hoping for something a bit more poetic.

Comment: *Life-changing poem?* ;)

Comment: Well, I mean, you're right. Those are certainly the most common terms for them. :)

Comment: 2 downvotes already! What is wrong with this question? Has it defied some arcane rule of english stackexchange?

Comment: [Hazelnut macchiato](https://www.google.com/search?q=carmal+mocioto+change+you+life&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22robot+chicken%22+caramel+macchiato+change+your+life).

Comment: I wish there was a simple term for Constantine's vision before the Battle of Milvern Bridge, BC that is your scenario.

Comment: You could use the adjective "pivotal", or any of its synonyms -- central, crucial, vital, critical, focal, essential, key, decisive.

Comment: (There is another word that would be a real good fit, but it's escaping me right now.)

Comment: Or perhaps "climax" or one of its synonyms -- climacteric, turning point, corner, landmark, milepost, milestone, watershed.  **"Watershed"**, especially, is often used in the sense of a life-altering event.

Comment: @HotLicks I like your suggestions of landmark & watershed, but for objects (rather than events) I think they are mostly understood to refer to the producer of the work, or the field of the work, but not the consumer(s) of the work.

Comment: It's not clear which of the two contexts the word should describe: that of a single object as in biographical tales or the collection of these from other's lives in your life.

Comment: Perhaps adjectives like "founding, fundational, fundamental" (as in founding event) or "edifying" (serving to educate or inform).

Answer (score 4):

When I think of books and albums that really have an effect on someone, I think they're *transformational*.  Is that what you're going for?

Answer (score 2):

You can consider ***influence*** as a single word.

> a person or thing that affects someone or something in an important way [[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/influence)

Example:

> Livingstone’s interest in science and nature led him to investigate the relationship between religion and science and in 1832 he read Philosophy of a Future State by science teacher and minister Thomas Dick. **The book was a big influence on him and helped reconcile his faith and science.**
>
> [[heraldscotland.com]](http://www.heraldscotland.com/news/home-news/from-the-archive-david-livingstone.2013038271)

---

However, the usual phrase is ***life-changing < something >***.

> *life-changing:* *(adj)* having an effect that is strong enough to change someone's life [[Cambridge]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/life-changing)

For example, *goodreads.com* has a section called "[life changing book lists](http://www.goodreads.com/list/tag/life-changing)".

Comment: Yeah influential or life-changing. Those are both good.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps **seminal** as the ellipsis of the phrase *seminal event*.

Comment: Seminal is more starting something than altering it, which is a slightly different perspective to look at something from.

Comment: @RobertGrant I won't claim to be the first person to mint a seminal, only a person. Once coined, the value is that for which it exchanges. Fungible are words as money.

Comment: I'm not if that's meant to be a haiku, but I don't understand it :) Fungible means that it doesn't matter where something comes from, it's worth the same, e.g. oil is oil. Just as it shouldn't matter who's saying a word, it means the same thing. Are you trying to say that words can randomly change their meanings? Seminal is to do with a seed or semen-like act, event or object. One that starts whatever it was seminal for. The seminal act for a person is fairly obvious.

Comment: Fungibility is a measure of the variety of goods and services for which something can be exchanged. Cash is more fungible than fill dirt. A word newly coined is more fungible than "dextrose." Some words provide more flexibility than others. None provide more than those we invent on the spot. I invented or reinvented "seminal" as ellipses. It is not yet so ossified  that yoga will break it.

Comment: So you're saying that some words can randomly change their meanings. I'd suggest that the 1350-1400s word "seminal", which is clearly related to "semen" is not one of those words, and if you use it in a different context you might happily think that you said "lifechanging" (in this case), or "hamster" or whatever else you decide it means today, but to the person on the other end you will still mean "originating".

Comment: @RobertGrant I said what I said. A strawman's creator owns it not its target. My OED shows the word *seminal*'s evolution from the mid 14th to the late 17th centuries CE. First we treat words as lumber, now as seed, each in turn  depending on our need.

Comment: What I'm saying is: this is a question about finding an appropriate word for a concept, not taking a random word and suggesting that. Why not suggest "Confetti" instead, and see how well that communicates the concept?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20762/discussion-between-ben-rudgers-and-robert-grant).

Answer (score 1):

**Fetish** in its technical sense from social science is close. It captures the idea of an object carrying symbolic importance. The sexual connotation accumulated through contemporary common use may or may not cater to the kink of a particular communication.

**Juju**'s metaphysical flexibility makes it about perfect, and extends naturally to collections via **juju bag**. But only if we are willing to step abroad from European word origins so far as to set foot in Africa.

Personally, I like the Ojibwa **totem** even though using it in the context of the personal rather than that of a community is perhaps a bit of legacy "me" generation narcissism. Like *juju*, *totem* captures the idea of collection and **totems** points to the collection rather than their container. But what I really like is that *totem* as a carved pole conveys ideas about order among and dependencies between the items.

Answer (score 0):

**red-letter**
red–let·ter \ˈred-ˌle-tər\ adjective

> of special significance
>
> From the practice of marking holy days in red letters in church calendars.
> First known use [of the word]: 1704 -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/red-letter)

The Romans had marked days in red going back to 509 BC.
Red-letter day -[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_letter_day)

Answer (score 0):

REDIRECTOR - (something) that directs (something) to a new or different place or purpose

- redirect (verb)
  to change the course or direction of https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redirect
- -or (noun suffix)
  one that does a specified thing https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/or

Answer (score -1):

might the word be: *profound*.Please see:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/profound

Answer (score -1):

[**Watershed**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/watershed)

A watershed is a turning point, or historic moment.